# Salesforce Integration User License, unable to assign Permission Set allowing Accounts, Leads, Contacts CRUD

Tags: salesforcedx, api, integration, licenses

Using just the Integration profile doesn't allow access to standard objects so it is advised to create a Permission Set (a.k.a PS) to allow CRUD access to standard objects like Accounts, Contacts, or Leads. See [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.integration_user.htm&type=5) and [here](https://elevation.solutions/resources/what-you-need-to-know-about-salesforce-integration-users/).

It is also advised to **not** select a `License` when creating the PS, which I did.

But after configuring the PS and upon assigning it to the user, I get the following error:

```
Failure : Can't assign ABC permission set to XYZ user. The user license doesn't allow the permission: Read Lead
```

OR

```
Failure : Can't assign ABC permission set to XYZ user. The user license doesn't allow the permission: Create Contact
```

OR

```
Failure : Can't assign ABC permission set to XYZ user. The user license doesn't allow the permission: Delete Contact
```

I'm not sure how to fix this issue and it is not pointed out anywhere.

Answer (score 11):

The issue is having the `License` field blank. If License is blank the user cannot be assigned to the PS.

To choose the correct license, if license is selected as `Salesforce Integration` under User Licenses category, this will still not work. The issue here is that standard objects will not be available in the PS to choose.

So the only way to achieve it is to make sure to select `Salesforce API Integration` under **Permission Set Licenses**.  This will show the std objects AND will allow the PS to be assigned to an integration user.

So do NOT choose `Salesforce Integration` under User Licenses category:
[image]

Instead, choose the `Salesforce API Integration` under **Permission Set Licenses**:
[image]

Comment: Why shouldn't Salesforce Integration be chosen? I created a PS with Salesforce API Integration as the license type, but then I found I couldn't give permission to custom objects, which means it's not suitable for what I want this user to do. I created one with Salesforce Integration and it only allowed access to custom objects.

Comment: That is odd but it is expected in some cases. So for some integrations, depending on type of access, you may need both permission sets created and assigned to the integration user. Combination of both PS will give you all the required access.

Comment: My God! Such a minor thing, and I wasted hours trying to find out what the issue was. Thank you so much!!

Comment: You save my day, i was going crazy !

Answer (score 1):

Assign 'Salesforce API Integration' permission to integration user from Permission Set License Assignments.